# Why do some cells in InfoPath 2013 appear white on SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, infopath

My form is a gray color with a blue heading, but some of the cells in the table appear white in SharePoint. When I view it in InfoPath, all cells are the correct color. However, when I upload to SharePoint, the color of some cells appear to be white. They appear to be random.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cells need to be bounded. Try editing the table and putting outlines set as the same color as the cell

Answer (score 0):

IF you have verified that the field background/color is correct as you want then this could be an issue with how IE is rendering your form. Update your IE if you are using an older version. Also try it on Google Chrome.